# Does reset could work against remote branch?

Tags: git

I saw that the command

```
 git reset --hard origin/master
```

is working via the remote tracking branch.

Is it possible to do reset against the remote branch and not the remote tracking branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Warning:  these commands have the power to change history.

#### Use them only if you understand and *accept* the risk.

The command `git reset --hard origin/master` wouldn't have an effect on a remote branch if it were applicable; effectively, what you're telling your **local** branch to do is to move HEAD to the same commit as reflected in `origin/master` as your repository knows it.  This will ***not*** touch your **remote** branch.

If `git fetch` wasn't run prior, you *do* run the risk of overwriting your local repository with an older variant of your remote repository, which is entirely fixable with `git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master`.

If you wanted to reset commits against your remote repository, you would have to first apply them to your local repository, then force-push them via `git push -f`.

Note that these kinds of changes that you do with respect to Git are done to your local repository first; if you want to publish them to your remote repository, you have to invoke different commands.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only way you can really interact with a remote branch from a Git client is by creating, pushing, or deleting a remote branch.  That being said, after running

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

you could force push your tracking branch to the remote via:

```
git push --force origin origin/master:master
```